# How to measure the number of JavaScript functions that define new Strings

Tags: javascript, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I was looking through [this paper](https://cs.ucsb.edu/~vigna/publications/2010_cova_kruegel_vigna_Wepawet.pdf), in which they use HTMLUnit to "measure the number of invocations of JavaScript functions that can be used to define new strings (such as substring, and fromCharCode), and the number of string uses (such as write operations and eval calls)."

I am new to HTMLUnit, and I can't seem to figure out how one can directly see the functions that a website is using and count which ones are substring, eval etc.? How exactly can this be done?

Comment: Hi, from the looks of it they use HTMLUnit as a starting point to develop jsand. HtmlUnit gives you hooking capabilities that you can then write handlers for to gather the metrics they feed into their ML

Comment: In particular you can see all the *\*Handlers* that  http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/ supports, and go from there when building your tests

Comment: @AhmedMasud HTMLUnit doesn't seem to have handlers for functions such as eval, they only provide handlers for prompt, alert, refresh, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is to monkeypatch all the native calls. For example:

```js
const original = String.fromCharCode;
String.fromCharCode = function(...args) {
  console.log('creating new string');
  return original.apply(this, args);
}
console.log(String.fromCharCode(65, 66, 67));
```

This allows you to keep the original functionality while still allowing you to keep track of what's going on. While more complex, the same can be applied (no pun intended) to `eval` and any other native call.
If you also want to monitor any DOM changes, you can use [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: it may be the most trivial approach  but surely not the easiest, and it doesn't have the coverage.

Comment: @Nit, I am still confused as to how we will use htmlunit here. Sorry, I am still new to the api. Thank you.